# use websocket in azure vm

Tags: c#, azure, websocket, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM running Windows Server 2012 R2.

I am trying to run a c# console application that utilizes TcpListener for websocket communication at port 8080. When I run my application locally it works fine. I get the initial GET request from the client and I can do the handshake and start sending data.

I copied over the .exe file for the console application to my server. However when I run the application in the server it doesn't work. I have defined the Inbound Firewall Rule for port 8080 on my Azure as well as on my server. When the console application is running on the server, I get the request from the client but it is not the initial GET request. Its gibberish (I don't know how else to explain that).

I have also installed WebSocket Protocol from the server manager.

Comment: Do you know if websockets in general work from where you are?  I keep seeing cases where (for example) corporate proxies/virus scanners etc break websockets.  That would be one reason for it working locally vs not working across the internet.  In that respect, [this website](http://websocketstest.com/) is a handy check.

Comment: Thank you for your response James Thorpe. I went to the website and it says "Websockets seem to work for you!" and I have all the green checks for all the ports.

Comment: ok - at least that's one area that can be ruled out then!

Comment: @JamesThorpe, any other suggestions I could try?

Comment: Can you show us the _gibberish_ you mention of?

Comment: Is it possible that you might also need an outbound firewall rule? Since Websockets is two way?

Comment: Did you try to disable the firewall on your VM ? Just to be sure it is or not the cause...

Comment: Are you using IIS?